# Dynamic 3D Variable-column character Array Manipulation in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

I would Like the following code to produce a structure like the one below the code. I do not get it from the code.

I want the code to create a 3D dynamic array that holds data as shown below such that when I want to print a specific string like `printf("%s\n",szData[2][3]);` I get `"string4"`. Also, I would like to get a specific character from a specific location e.g `putchar(szData[0][3][2]` I get `'r'`.

Instead the code below prints out the last saved data despite specifying a location. For example `printf("%s",szData[0][0]);` which should have been `"string1"` it prints out `"string2"` which is data for `szData[2][1]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char***szData;
    char temp[500];
    int i,j,k,x,n,m,index;

    printf("Rows:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    szData=(char***)malloc(n*sizeof(char));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Col: ");
        scanf("%d",&m);
        szData[i]=(char**)malloc(m*sizeof(char));
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){

            printf("string[%d][%d]=",i,j);
            scanf("%s",temp);
            szData[i][j]=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
            szData[i][j]=temp;

        }
    }


            printf("memmory[%d][%d]=%s\n",0,2,szData[0][2]);//Printing string from specific location


    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Expected structure:

     +----------+----------+----------+----------+
     |    0     |     1    |     2    |    3     |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 0  |  string1 |  string2 | string3  |string4   |
+----+----------+----------+----------+--------- +
     +----------+----------+
     |    0     |     1    | 
+----+----------+----------+
| 0  |  string1 |  string2 | 
+----+----------+----------+
     +----------+
     |    0     |      
+----+----------+
| 1  |  string1 |  
+----+----------+
     +----------+----------+----------+----------+
     |    0     |     1    |     2    |    3     |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2  |  string1 |  string2 | string3  |string4   |
+----+----------+----------+----------+--------- +
     +----------+----------+
     |    0     |     1    |     
+----+----------+----------+
| 2  |  string1 |  string2 | 
+----+----------+----------+
     +----------+----------+----------+----------+
     |    0     |     1    |     2    |    3     |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2  |  string1 |  string2 | string3  |string4   |
+----+----------+----------+----------+--------- +
     +----------+----------+
     |    0     |     1    |     
+----+----------+----------+
| 2  |  string1 |  string2 | 
+----+----------+----------+
```

---

The code bellow works fine. Why not the above?

```
#include <stdio,h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char***szData; 
    char temp[25];
    szData= (char *** )malloc(4 * sizeof(char ** )) ;
    szData[0]=(char**)malloc(2*sizeof(char));
    szData[0][0]=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
    szData[0][0]="Henry\0";
    szData[0][1]=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
    szData[0][1]="Korir\0";
    szData[1]=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char));
    szData[1][0]=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
    szData[1][0]="BSc.\0";
    szData[2]=(char**)malloc(3*sizeof(char));
    szData[2][0]=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
    szData[2][0]="Software Engineering\0";
    szData[2][1]=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
    szData[2][1]="Kenyatta\0 ";
    szData[2][2]=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
    szData[2][2]="University\0";
    szData[3]=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char));
    szData[3][0]=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
    szData[3][0]="From Kipsaiya, Kenya\0";

    printf("szData[%d][%d]=%c size=%d\n",0,1,szData[2][0][0],sizeof(szData[0][1]));
    strcpy(temp,szData[2][0]);
    putchar(szData[0][0][0]);
    printf("temp=%s size=%d\n",temp,sizeof(szData[2][0]));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542391/segmentation-fault-but-unable-to-reason-how-memory-allocation-looks-fine-to-me/35542617#35542617) (disclaimer: shameless plug).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your contribution.The code crushed amid execution. I would love to see an improvement to the code you supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These allocations are wrong

```
szData=(char***)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
                                ^^^^^ 
szData[i]=(char**)malloc(m*sizeof(char));
                                  ^^^^^
```

There should be

```
szData=(char***)malloc(n*sizeof(char **));
                                ^^^^^^^ 
szData[i]=(char**)malloc(m*sizeof(char *));
                                  ^^^^^^^
```

And instead of the assignment

```
szData[i][j]=temp;
```

that leads to a memory leak you have to use standard function `strcpy`

```
strcpy( szData[i][j], temp );
```

Also as the number of columns in each row is various then you should somehow to keep the information about the number of columns in a row.

One of approaches is to allocate one more column and set the last column to `NULL`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char ***szData;
    unsigned int n, m;
    unsigned int i, j;

    printf( "Rows: " );
    scanf( "%u", &n );

    szData = ( char*** )malloc( n * sizeof( char ** ) );

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Col: " );
        scanf( "%u", &m );

        szData[i] = ( char ** )calloc( ( m + 1 ), sizeof( char * ) );
        for ( j = 0; j < m; j++ )
        {
            char temp[25];
            printf( "string[%u][%u] = ", i, j );
            scanf( "%24s", temp );
            szData[i][j] = ( char * )malloc( strlen( temp ) + 1 );
            strcpy( szData[i][j], temp );
        }
    }

    printf( "\n" );

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; szData[i][j] != NULL; j++ ) printf( "%10s", szData[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }        

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; szData[i][j] != NULL; j++ ) free( szData[i][j] );;
        free( szData[i] );
    }

    free( szData );             

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Rows: 7
Col: 4
string[0][0] = string1
string[0][1] = string2
string[0][2] = string3
string[0][3] = string4
Col: 2
string[1][0] = string1
string[1][1] = string2
Col: 1
string[2][0] = string1
Col: 4
string[3][0] = string1
string[3][1] = string2
string[3][2] = string3
string[3][3] = string4
Col: 2
string[4][0] = string1
string[4][1] = string2
Col: 4
string[5][0] = string1
string[5][1] = string2
string[5][2] = string3
string[5][3] = string4
Col: 2
string[6][0] = string1
string[6][1] = string2

   string1   string2   string3   string4
   string1   string2
   string1
   string1   string2   string3   string4
   string1   string2
   string1   string2   string3   string4
   string1   string2
```

EDIT: After you updated your question then the code like this

```
szData[0][0]=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
szData[0][0]="Henry\0";
```

is also wrong.

There is at least a memory leak because at first `szData[0][0]` was assigned with the address of the allocated memory and then in the next statement it was reassigned.

Also there is no need to write string literals like `"Henry\0"` because string literal `"Henry"` already has the terminating zero.

Comment: Great.! Now I know better.

Answer (score 1):

`szData[i][j]=temp;` right after `szData[i][j]=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));` is causing memory leak.

Allocate enough memory and copy the string read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char***szData;
    char temp[500];
    int i,j,k,x,n,m,index;

    printf("Rows:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    szData=malloc(n*sizeof(char**));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Col: ");
        scanf("%d",&m);
        szData[i]=malloc(m*sizeof(char*));
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){

            printf("string[%d][%d]=",i,j);
            scanf("%499s",temp);
            szData[i][j]=malloc((strlen(temp)+1)*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(szData[i][j],temp);

        }
    }


    printf("memmory[%d][%d]=%s\n",0,2,szData[0][2]);//Printing string from specific location

    return 0;
}
```

Note that they say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your contribution.The code crushed amid execution. I would love to see an improvement to the code you supplied.

Comment: It didn't crash in [my test](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/E0719fNj329QNe0Y). What is your input?

Comment: I used random strings like names. More so, I had to typecast `malloc` for it to compile in my machine.