# C - function that allocates memory

Tags: c, function, pointers, matrix, allocation

I've written a procedure, that creates 2 matrices and multiplies them. However I have to divide my code into functions, and I have a problem with declaring a function that will allocate the memory for matrices.

Here's my code:

```
void matrixMult(){
int **A, **B, **C; //matrices
int rowA, colA, rowB, colB; //rows and columns 
int i, j, k; //for iterations

printf("Number of rows in matrix A: \n");
scanf("%d", &rowA);
printf("Number of columns in matrix A: \n");
scanf("%d", &colA);

printf("Number of rows in matrix B: \n");
scanf("%d", &rowB);
printf("Number of columns in matrix B: \n");
scanf("%d", &colB);

//memory allocation
A = (int**)malloc(rowA * sizeof(int));
B = (int**)malloc(rowB * sizeof(int));
C = (int**)malloc(rowA * sizeof(int));

for (i = 0; i < rowA; i++)
  {
   A[i] = (int*)malloc(colA * sizeof(int));
  }

for (i = 0; i < rowB; i++)
  {
   B[i] = (int*)malloc(colB * sizeof(int));
  }

for (i = 0; i < rowA; i++)
  {
   C[i] = (int*)malloc(colB * sizeof(int));
  } 
/* 
the rest of code
*/
}
```

What should this function look like?

Comment: What's wrong with it? Does it not work? Is it slow? Does it cause memory leaks? Is it ugly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542391/segmentation-fault-but-unable-to-reason-how-memory-allocation-looks-fine-to-me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @Beta well, the bad indentation sure does not make it pretty.

Comment: One of the usual suspects can provide the link: Don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: There are no matrices (i.e. 2D arrays) in your code. Nor something that can point to them.

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways of doing it that are both used in practice:

- **Write a function that allocates the matrix and returns the result** - your function would have the following signature: `int **alloc_matrix(size_t rows, size_t columns)`
- **Write a function that takes a pointer to matrix pointer, and returns a status code** - the signature would be `int alloc_matrix(int*** res, size_t rows, size_t columns)`

The value returned from the second function would indicate a success or a failure in allocating the memory.

Comment: Actually for a matrix/2d array, this is wrong. OP should use a correct 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

The first allocation you have an error. You have to alocate an array of pointers to Ints.

```
A= (int**)malloc(rowA * sizeof(int*));
B = (int**)malloc(rowB * sizeof(int*));
C = (int**)malloc(rowA * sizeof(int*));
```

for the function problem

```
int** alocatingArray(size_t nRows, size_t nCols){
...
}
```

this function will be used to each array returning the primary pointer to the matrix